How to configure SSO between Sharepoint 2019 onprime and Nintex K2 5.5?
I have a sharepoint 2019 onprim app that uses Nintex K2 forms in Ifram, Everytime the user login to the sharepoint app using his windows creds. the k2 asks to enter the creds again.
So how can we configure Singl Sign On between the sharepoint app and K2.
The expectation is to Make the K2 forms not ask again for the usernam and password
